# Too slow Ubuntu after upgrading to 16.10

Tags: performance, 16.10

I've upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10 by software updater but now my system works too slow for example it boots too slow and runs applications too slow. What should I do ?

Comment: Could you please give some more details ? How long boottime ? What applications are "slow" and how much ?

Comment: almost every applications are slow and boot time is about 1 minute I think

Comment: What's the problem ? A boot time at one minute isn't bad. And that "almost every application are slow" is way to fluffy to give any advise on. But maybe your system needs more memory. Try to run 'top' in a terminal to see how much memory is used and which processes are taking up cpu.

Answer (score 0):

I've found few solutions but one very effective with Bleachbit, very effective to clean all caches, temps and memory
www.bleachbit.org

first enter as adminstrator with and input your password:
sudo su
apt-get install bleachbit

later run with:
bleachbit

very effective aside to use the right controller for your video card and right setting of swappiness %